# tabindicator is not sliding from one to another tab in tablayout when I swipe between fragments. Highlighting of font is also not changing

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

```
public class LoginRegister extends AppCompatActivity implements SignUpFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener ,SignInFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_register);
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_signup);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Sign Up"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Sign in"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);        
    final ViewPager pager =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.loginpager);
    final SigninPagerAdapter adapter = new SigninPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
}
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
```

when I slide through fragments, the highlights of the tab does not changes, But it works fine when I touch the tabs.When I touch them, the tab indicator slides well from left to right and font color of tabs also looks highlighted.
I think Problem is in this piece of code

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
}
```

What should I do to Highlight current tab...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found my solution.

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```

this method sets everything easily.

Answer (score 2):

Just an additional note.

Best thing to do is call `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)` last.

At least, don't call `viewPager.clearOnPageChangeListeners()` or `viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()` right after you called `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)` because that will remove the listener that TabLayout uses when the `ViewPager` is scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't addTab() on your tablayout because you've already set up a view pager adapter

Do the following and it should work fine

```
public class LoginRegister extends AppCompatActivity implements SignUpFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener ,SignInFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_register);

    final SigninPagerAdapter adapter = new SigninPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.loginpager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_signup);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    }
}
```

And **SignInPagerAdapter**

```
public class SigninPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0: 
            return SingnUpFragment.newInstance()
        case 1: 
            return SignInFragment.newInstance()
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return the number of tabs you want in your tabLayout
        return 2;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        //this is where you set the titles
        switch(position) {
            case 0: 
                return "Sign Up";
            case 1:
                return "Sign In";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: when I removed addTab(), the titles of the tabs also got removed.

Comment: Take a look at the adapter code. Did you override getPageTitle in your adapter? That's where you set the titles

Comment: Yes, getpagetitle is overridden there,but still titles are not visible

Comment: Apologies, seems i've forgotten to set up the viewpager with the tablayout. Add tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager) just below setTabGravity. I've edited the code, take a look

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of selected and unselected tab. Use the following code in your LoginRegister.java file:

```
//tabLayout.setTabTextColors(unselectedTabColor, selectedTabColor)
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#627179"), Color.parseColor("#BF4A32"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try add this in yout code:

```
 mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            //THIS!!
            if (mViewPager != null) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

It solved my problem.